# stackblitz typescript project doesn't know BigInt

Tags: typescript, stackblitz

When you create a typescript project on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jzntuk) it turns out that there is an issue with [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

[image]

```
const val = BigInt(10);
```

It doesn't know `BigInt`. Although the code runs fine I still want the error to go away :)

So, in the above case I can add the follow

```
declare function BigInt(inp: number | string);
```

This works, the error is gone. But when I add more code, like this

```
declare function BigInt(inp: number | string);

function convert(inp: string): BigInt {
    return BigInt(inp);
}

const val = BigInt(10);
```

The `declare` at the top is not enough

[image]

It complains that BigInt refers to a value and is being used as a Type.

I'm not sure any more what I can do to fix this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BigInt` isn't a part of typescript, it is a part of javascript of some browsers, but Safari for example doesn't support it, that means code without a polyfill won't work there.

To define it properly you need to declare its interface, its variable and its constructor.

```js
declare interface BigInt {
  // here all magic you want to declare
  test: number
};

declare var BigInt: BigIntConstructor;

declare interface BigIntConstructor {
    new(value?: any): BigInt;
    (value?: any): BigInt;
    readonly prototype: BigInt;
};



function convert(inp: string): BigInt {
    return BigInt(inp);
}

const val = BigInt(10).test; // an example.
```